How to pick specific file format via an Intent in Android?
In my application, I need to pick these (sfa, sfb, fbx, obj) specific files which I have saved before, from the file manager in an Android device across different providers
I tried this
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
      intent.setType("*/*");
      intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
      intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
      //intent.putExtra("CONTENT_TYPE", "*/*");

   activityResultLauncher.launch(intent);

but it always opens like this, I don't see any file manager here

If anyone knows how to do this with these file formats (sfa, sfb, fbx, obj) across different providers (Samsung,Pixel etc...), please leave your solution, it would be very helpful

// add this
String[] mimeTypes = {"model/sfa", "model/sfb", "model/fbx", "model/obj"};
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
// remove this
intent.setType("*/*");

Above code will allow the user to select only file types from this list: sfa, sfb, fbx, obj

Hi sir, thanks for your answer, but it opens like this https://i.sstatic.net/H3Qxyo6O.png

If this does not work then, you should allow the user to pick a file ie. just use intent.setType("*/*"); & then, check if the picked file is from your required file types.

Try this:
Intent intent;
if (android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER.equalsIgnoreCase("samsung")) {
    intent = new Intent("com.sec.android.app.myfiles.PICK_DATA");
    intent.putExtra("CONTENT_TYPE", "*/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
} else {

    String[] mimeTypes =
            {"application/msword", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", // .doc & .docx
                    "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation", // .ppt & .pptx
                    "application/vnd.ms-excel", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", // .xls & .xlsx
                    "text/plain",
                    "application/pdf",
                    "application/zip", "application/vnd.android.package-archive"};

    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); // or ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
}

replace with your mineTypes.
